# Чому багато із тих, хто вважає українську мову своєю рідною, не говорять нею навіть у публічних місцях?

Tags: соціолінгвістика

За даними останнього офіційного перепису населення України, [68% громадян України вважають українську мову своєю рідною. В тому числі, наприклад, серед мешканців Києва цей показник складає 72%](http://2001.ukrcensus.gov.ua/results/general/language/city_kyiv/).

Водночас, де-факто навіть у Києві частка людей, що говорять українською в публічних місцях (в магазинах, кафе, на виставках, концертах тощо), за моїми суб'єктивними спостереженнями, є суттєво меншою, аніж частка людей, що вважають українську мову рідною.

В чому **головні** причини такої невідповідності?

Comment: В будь-якому разі, дослідження та соціологічні опитування підтверджують існування такої невідповідності. За даними групи "Рейтинг", наприклад, українською вдома спілкуються в тому ж-таки Києві 27%. http://osvita.mediasapiens.ua/mediaprosvita/research/analitichniy_oglyad_stanovische_ukrainskoi_movi_v_20142015_rokakh/

Comment: Можливо проблема в тому, що опитування не уточнюють, що таке "рідна мова". Наприклад, у переписі 2001-го року використовувалась така форма: http://2001.ukrcensus.gov.ua/img/f2c-1.gif
Як бачите, питання саме про те, яку мову респондент вважає рідною, а не про те, яку мову вони вивчили першою чи якою мовою розмовляють їх батьки.
Ще одне можливе пояснення - системна помилка при підрахунку. Наприклад, якщо незаповнені поля рахувались як "українець" так "українська".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Справа в тому, що українська незалежна та самостійна державність переживала не дуже легкі часи багато років, десятиліть та сторіччь поспіль. Російський імперіалізм насаджував російську мову, українська заборонялася не тільки для друку, а й для вживання. Боялася мови як царська Росія, та і СРСР. І роками пропоганди створювали образ цієї мови як "мови селюків".

На жаль, це генетично на поколіннях десь слугує перемикачем, тому багато хто соромиться, що засміють, що, буцімто, не зрозуміють та будуть вважати людиною другого сорту. Мають пройти роки, знову ж не одне покоління ве незалежної України, тоді це якось зміниться.

Взагалі, навіть лячно чути фразу на кшталт "В центрі Києва вам зможуть відповісти українською". Чому ніхто так не каже про французьку в центрі Парижу, італійську в Римі чи польську в Варшаві?

Answer (score 9):

Нам прищеплена нетерпимість і меншовартість до рідної ж мови. Часто буває так що соромно заговорити українською мовою - бо будуть зглядатись люди, у нас в Миколаєві наприклад так і є. Вдома всі говорять не те щоб українською, а суржиком який складається відсотків на 65 з українських слів, на 10 російських а решта зросійщені мутанти українсько-російських слів.

Все це нам прищепили загарбники які панували, та в принципі й панують понині у владних кабінетах іноземці (московити або їх посіпаки). Варто згадати як знищували українську мову при СРСР, при російській імперії було багато указів, які забороняли викладання, друк і використання української мови, Емський указ як мінімум тому доказ.

Comment: До вас те ж прохання, що й до автора попередньої відповіді. Ви могли б деталізувати вашу відповідь? Бо незрозуміло звідки і ким прищеплена нетерпимість та меншовартість.

Answer (score 7):

1922 – проголошення частиною керівництва ЦК РКП(б) і ЦК КП(б)У «теорії» боротьби в Україні двох культур – міської (російської) та селянської (української), в якій перемогти повинна перша. Під окупацією СРСР російській мові надавався статус просвітницької, носії російської мови вважались культурно і духовно вищими - це була свідома політика приниження мови автохтонів радянських республік. Ця їдеологія розвивається ще й досі добровільно зросійщеними корисними ідіотами і керівництвом росії.

Answer (score 5):

**Доповнено**

1. **Сила звички**: в СРСР загальноприйнятою була російська. Нею традиційно спілкувались скрізь: на підприємствах, в університетах, школах тощо. З розвалом псевдоімперії люди опинились в ситуації, коли можна говорити як хочеш, бо старі правила вже не діяли, а нові або ще не існували, або були відірвані від реальності. Тож за звичкою багато наших співвітчизників продовжували спілкуватись російською, а до того ж нею виховувати дітей.
2. **Іншомовне оточення**: я з Дніпра, російськомовного міста. Більшість моїх україномовних однокурсників, що приїждали з сіл, поступово переходили на російську, бо майже всі навколо так говорили. Були ситуації, коли навіть між собою такі студенти вживали російську.
3. **Непрестижність**. Варто згадати хоча б «Бєлую ґвардію» Булґакова, де українська принижувалась, як мова другого ґатунку.

Ось цитата для пояснення третього пункту:

> Сволочь он,- с ненавистью продолжал Турбин,- ведь он же сам не говорит
>   на этом проклятом языке! А? (*209) Я позавчера спрашиваю эту каналью,
>   доктора Курицького, он, извольте ли видеть, разучился говорить
>   по-русски с ноября прошлого года. Был Курицкий, а стал Курицький...
>   Так вот спрашиваю: как по-украински "кот"? Он отвечает: "Кит".
>   Спрашиваю: "А как кит?" А он остановился, вытаращил глаза и молчит. И
>   теперь не кланяется.

Я після багатьох років в російськомовному місті зрозумів це і побачив, що звички можна міняти, оточення — теж, а третє питання суто особисте.